# Extending web service proxy classes to add extra methods in c#

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service, in operation contract for that service I would like to add extra functionality.

So here is the case, Proxy class has a contract `executeCreatePaperClipTransaction` and `executeCreateLoanIncrease` as separate classes. What I want is `executeCreateLoanIncrease` **should be child object of parent class** `executeCreatePaperClipTransaction`.

*Reason I am doing this is, WSDL which I am using is managed by some vendor and he didn't have provision to add this field as part of DataContract. But the same is working with XML request.*

I am trying to put minimal and useful code over here as both proxy classes contain a lot of properties.

**Original Proxy Classes From WSDL** :

```
public partial class executeCreatePaperClipTransaction : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private CreatePaperClipTransactionType createPaperClipTransactionField; 

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public CreatePaperClipTransactionType CreatePaperClipTransaction {
        //Getter and Setter Methods; 
    }   
}

public partial class CreatePaperClipTransactionType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string effectiveDateField;          

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string effectiveDate {
       //Getter and Setter Methods; 
    }
}

public partial class executeCreateLoanIncrease : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private CreateLoanIncreaseType createLoanIncreaseField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public CreateLoanIncreaseType CreateLoanIncrease {
         //Getter and Setter Methods; 
    }
}

public partial class CreateLoanIncreaseType : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string loanAliasField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string loanAlias {
         //Getter and Setter Methods; 
    }
}
```

My code:

```
[XmlType("executeCreatePaperClipTransaction")]
public partial class CustomExecuteCreatePaperClipTransaction : executeCreatePaperClipTransaction
{        
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CreatePaperClipTransaction", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction { get; set; }        
}   

public partial class CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType : CreatePaperClipTransactionType
{
    [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public executeCreateLoanIncrease ObjLoanIncreaseRequest { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create an object of my custom class and pass that object to proxy operation contract it gives me an error saying "**The type was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.**"

- *I am assuming this might be the problem:*

When i serialize `req` object it generate xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<executeCreatePaperClipTransaction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CreatePaperClipTransaction /* SomeAttributesAreHere */>
        <ObjLoanIncreaseRequest>
            <CreateLoanIncrease loanAlias="N00001" />
        </ObjLoanIncreaseRequest>
    </CreatePaperClipTransaction>
</executeCreatePaperClipTransaction>
```

I noticed that i do not want `ObjLoanIncreaseRequest` XML tag. When I remove that tag and execute the same XML directly from SoapUI. **It worked!** :)

Any idea what I am missing in the code?

Comment: why not use knowntype attribute for executeCreateLoanIncrease?

Comment: @HameedSyed: Do you want me to modify `References.cs`?

Comment: My bad for understanding the question in wrong way :(

Comment: I don't get it. Why anyone would want to add anything to data contract. If the service is able to "handle" another method (or to receive additional data in existing contracts) - then wsdl file must be changed (and it must be supported by the service)

Comment: @Piotr: WSDL is managed by some third party vendor and I can't change that. That's why I am looking for an alternative.

Comment: But if you change the xml message making it incomprehensible for this "third party vendor" - it will throw an error on partner side during communication

Comment: @Piotr: I am not changing XML message. I am building my custom class in such a way that when it is serialized it should match with what is expected by service. The problem is vendor "FORGOT" to put those methods as part of WSDL but it's working through `XML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.

Instead of extending the proxy DataContract, I could add it in the existing class. As it is a partial class. I just have to make sure that namespace of WSDL and custom class matches.

```
namespace MyProject.Service // This is important 
{
    public partial class executeCreatePaperClipTransaction
    {        
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CreatePaperClipTransaction", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public CustomCreatePaperClipTransactionType ObjCreatePaperClipTransaction { get; set; }        
    }   

    public partial class CreatePaperClipTransactionType
    {
        [XmlElement(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
        public executeCreateLoanIncrease ObjLoanIncreaseRequest { get; set; }
    }
}
```