# how to make asynchronous static method with same generic array param and same generic array return type

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I want to do all of the same code twice, but just for two different objects.  I am getting these objects from a SOAP API (rather outdated one).
I want to avoid writing duplicate code over and over again.  I'll be taking my original object and manipulating it a lot (all the same way)  the only difference is that the object type is the difference, so that's why I need to make a generic object.  I want it to return the same type as it takes as a parameter.  I am having an issue that if I do code like this

```
public static class ParamsHelper<T>
{
    public static async Task<T[]> Whatever(T[] rptParams)
    {
        //do some stuff to rptparams
        return rptParams;
    }
}

//  then I call it like this below:
var params = await  ParamsHelper.Whatever<ItemP[]>(new ItemP[]{});

//  it says can't convert type ItemP[] to type ItemP[][].
```

Additionally, I am using LINQ to do all of the manipulating.  I would love advice on how to access the object fields (maybe reflection?)

Comment: your last sentence should be a separate question.

Comment: Generics are not usually helpful when you are working with individual objects, because the generic objects have no known properties. Generics shine when working with lists, arrays, dictionaries etc. When working with individual objects you can achieve reusability with interfaces.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias can you give a code sample of how I could achieve this with an interface?

Comment: @Leah you said that you have two different objects, and some duplicate code for these objects. Do they have any common properties? If yes, then you should be able to define an [`interface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) with these common properties, and then make sure that both objects implement this interface. After that you should be able to modify your existing code to work with this interface instead of the concrete classes.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I cannot implement the interface from these objects because they are not my objects.  They are soap api objects

Comment: @Leah it should be possible to implement a custom interface by extending the SOAP objects. Typically you'll need to make the classes partial. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489330/extending-web-service-proxy-classes-to-add-extra-methods-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the generic type on the method.

```
public static async Task<T[]> Whatever<T>(T[] rptParams)
```

The usage generally is implied from usage so you don't have to pass it.

if you do have to pass it, dont make it an array.

```
ParamsHelper.Whatever<ItemP>(new ItemP[] { });
```

Comment: and what about my class ParamsHelper<T>?  Is that okay?

Comment: it just creates confusion IMO